Finding the radius of circle internally tangent to circles of known radii, given length of their common tangent
The question- Let $A$ and $B$ be two externally tangent circles with radii $2$ and $3$ respectively. Let both of them touch a circle $C$ internally at $P$ and $Q$, if the tangent to $C$ at $P$ and $Q$ intersect at $T$ such that $TP$ is equal to 4, find the radius of the circle $C$
My method- I used coordinate geometry by letting the circles A and B (their centre on x axis) and then using pure coordinate geometry to find the circle C , it's tangent, and point of contact P, and then using distance formula, but it was too lengthy although I got the answer
I tried using sine/cosine rule, but I end up with 0=0, I wonder if there is really a pure geometrical solution of this question

From the cosine rule applied to triangles $TPQ$ and $CPQ$ we obtain:
$$
\tag{1}
32+32\cos\alpha=2r^2-2r^2\cos\alpha,
$$
where $r=CP=CQ$ and $\alpha=\angle PCQ$.
From the cosine rule applied to triangle $CAB$ we obtain:
$$
\tag{2}
(r-2)^2+(r-3)^2 -2(r-2)(r-3)\cos\alpha=25.
$$
Solving $(1)$ for $\cos\alpha$ and inserting the result into $(2)$ we get a quadratic equation for $r$:
$$
r^2-8r=0,
$$
that is $r=8$.
EDIT.
Note that this works for any value of the parameters. If $a$ and $b$ are the radii of circles $A$ and $B$ respectively, and $c=TP=TQ$, then by the same reasoning explained above one gets:
$$
r={c^2(a+b)\over c^2-ab}.
$$
Of course it must be $c^2>ab$, otherwise circle $C$ doesn't exist.

A good no-calculator approach. But did you go into it knowing - or only trusting - that quartic and cubic terms would cancel for an easy polynomial?

@RobinSparrow Allez en avant, et la foi vous viendra...

@RobinSparrow More seriously, I think the disappearing of higher order terms is a signal that an Euclidean construction should be possible.

Right you are =)

We seek $PC=QC$. Note

$BQT$ is a $3/4/5$ right triangle
$APT$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{20}$
$TBA$ is isosceles with side length $5$ and base $\sqrt{20}$

Solution with trig:
Since we have the triangles, trig yields angles, thus angle $PTQ$, call that $2\omega$, then $\tan{\omega}=\frac{PC}{PT}=\frac{PC}{4} \rightarrow PC=8$ and $\omega \approx 63.4 ^{\circ}$
A synthetic Euclidean approach without trig:
As before, note $\triangle{BQT}$ is a $3/4/5$ right triangle, that $\triangle{ATP}$ is a right triangle with hypotenuse $\sqrt{20}$, and that $\triangle{ABT}$ is isosceles with sides $5$ and base $\sqrt{20}$.
Extend $BT$ so $BT=BD$ and we now have $BT=BA=BD$ so that $DT$ is a diameter of a circle on $B$ and $\triangle{ADT}$ is right. Set $\alpha=\angle{D}$, $\alpha'=90-\alpha$, and populate corners of $\triangle{ADT}$ accordingly.
But then note the hypotenuse $DT=10$, and $AT=\sqrt{20}$, so $AD=\sqrt{80}$. So $\frac{AD}{AT}=\frac{\sqrt{80}}{\sqrt{20}}=\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}=\frac{2}{1}$. But $\frac{PT}{AT}=\frac{2}{1}$. So right triangles $\triangle{ATP}$ and $\triangle{TDA}$ are similar, so $\angle{ATP}=\alpha$. But then the angle $PTD$ is right, so $PC \parallel TD$.
But this then implies $\angle{PCQ}=\angle{TBQ}$ and further since $\angle{PCQ}=2\angle{TCQ}=\angle{TBQ}$ that $C$ lies on the circle of radius $5$ on $B$ so that $BC=5$ and thus $CQ=CP=8$.


Here is a trigonometry-based solution.
Let $r$ be the looked-for radius.
Let
$$\angle PCQ = \alpha \ \ \text{and} \ \ t:=\tan \tfrac{\alpha}{2}\tag{0}$$
I say that $r$ and $t$ are (unique) solutions to the following system
$$\begin{cases}(1a) \ \ &25&=&(r-2)^2+(r-3)^2-2(r-2)(r-3)(1-t^2)/(1+t^2)\\(1b) \ \ &\tfrac{(r+4t)^2}{1+t^2}&=&r^2+4^2\end{cases}$$
Let $A$ and $B$ denote the centers of circles $(A)$ and $(B)$.
First of all : $TP=TQ=4$ and $PQ=2+3=5$.
As quadrangle $PCQT$ has right angles in $P$ and $Q$, $\angle PTQ = \pi - \alpha$ (the sum of the internal angles in $PCQT$ being equal to $2 \pi$).
Eq. (1a) comes from cosine rule applied to triangle $ACB$ (and classical half-angle formulas ; see notations of (0)).
Eq. (1b) comes from the following calculation:
Let $I = PQ \cap CT$. Let us write that :
$$CT=CI+IT$$
Using the fact that $CT$ is the internal angle bissector of $\angle PCQ$ :
$$CT=r \cos \tfrac{\alpha}{2}+4 \underbrace{\cos(\tfrac{\pi}{2}-\tfrac{\alpha}{2})}_{\sin \tfrac{\alpha}{2}} \tag{2}$$
Besides, by Pythagoras $CT=\sqrt{r^2+4^2}$. Plugging this expression into (2), eq. (1b) is readily obtained.
Using a CAS (I have used Sage ; you can use Wolfram Alpha), system (1a)+(1b) has a (unique solution) :
$$r=8, \ \ t=1/2$$
which means that
$$\angle PCQ = \alpha = 2 \tan^{-1}\tfrac12$$
